# TabLayout contentscrim not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I imagine TabLayout contentScrim works the same as CollapsingToolbar contentScrim; that is, for `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` the scrim color should show when the user is scrolling back down after some scrolling up. But the TabLayout contenScrim is not showing. How might I accomplish this behavior? For comparison the google Newsstand app does it.